# What is the relation between "signature_algorithms" handshake extension and TLS ciphersuite

Tags: tls, hash, digital-signature, handshake

I am learning TLS handshake and find client/serve will negotiate a cihpersuite during client/server hello.

Usually, the last part of a ciphersuite is a hash algorithm, like `SHA256` in `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256`. The second part of a ciphersuite is public key algorithm of server certificate like `ECDSA`. As we know, public key is usually capable of signing a message.

I also noticed in the client Hello, there is [an extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.4.1) called `signature_algorithms` to set the preferred hash/signature algorithm pairs. The chosen hash/signature is usually used to sign the Server Key Exchange.

My question is: since the ciphersuite already indicates both hash and signature algorithms, why we still needs the `signature_algorithms` extension?

Comment: It matters whether you are using TLS1.2 or 1.3. In 1.2 sigalgs (13) controls both the protocol-message signature (server must use algorithm specified in ciphersuite, but can choose hash) _and_ signatures of certs in the chain; in 1.3 there are _two_ extensions: sigalgscert (50) if present controls certs in chain, while sigalgs always controls protocol-message (which now is NOT constrained by the ciphersuite) _and_ controls certs in chain IF sigalgscert is NOT present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... since the ciphersuite already indicates both hash and signature algorithms

The hash given ciphersuite only defines the algorithms used for the integrity protection of the encrypted traffic, i.e. the HMAC. These are not for digital signatures. Similar the public key algorithm in the cipher suite is only about the public key of the server certificate used for authentication. It is not about public key of the client certificate nor about signatures used for the certificates.

Comment: How does public key of server certificate is used for authentication? BTW, server seems to sign the Server Key Exchange record before sending to client. Which signature is used for the sign, the one from `signature_algorithms` or the public key from certificate?

Comment: I used Wireshark to analyse TLS handshake. It seems that server does **not** send client the chosen *signature algorithm*, right?

Comment: @Zachary: The public key of the certificate is used within authentication to check the signature done by the server using the matching private key. And there is no "agreeing" on signature algorithms, only announcing what is supported by the client. Whenever a signature is used by the server it is clear from the signature itself which algorithms were used.

Comment: About the authentication, what I learned is: the cert is signed by issuer CA. Do you mean to verify the signature from CA? Or where is the signature from during the handshake?

Comment: @Zachary: Authentication is done by checking that the server owns the private key matching the certificate - by letting the server creating a signature with this key. Of course, validation of the certificate chain is relevant too - which includes checking the issuer signatures on the certificates along the trust path.

Comment: Steffen, many thanks for your patience. "by letting the server creating a signature with this key" (the private key): when is this signature signed during the handshake and which part is signed by the private key?

Comment: @Zachary: This moves more and more out of the scope of your original questions. Comments are not intended to ask and answer new questions. In short: see CertificateVerify in [RFC 8446 section 4.4.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#section-4.4.3).

Comment: Great reference.

Comment: Hash in 1.2 or lower ciphersuite controls the HMAC _unless_ the cipher is AEAD (only in 1.2), and in 1.2 only also the 'PRF' (KDF) for new suites but not pre-1.2 ones; hash in 1.3 ciphersuite controls only the KDF because all ciphers are AEAD

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 If I am right, AEAD has built-in HMAC, right?

Comment: @Zachary: AEAD has builtin _authentication_; that's what 'Authenticated Encryption' means. It doesn't have to be HMAC and usually isn't; the AEAD ciphers (currently) defined for TLS are ChaCha20+Poly1305 and AES-GCM, which both use keyed polynomial-residue MACs, and AES-CCM, which uses CBC-MAC.